# Loading remote images

Tags: android, image, imageview

In Android, what is the simplest approach to the following:

1. Load an image from a remote server.
2. Display it in an ImageView.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's a method that I actually used in an application and I know it works:

```
try {
    URL thumb_u = new URL("http://www.example.com/image.jpg");
    Drawable thumb_d = Drawable.createFromStream(thumb_u.openStream(), "src");
    myImageView.setImageDrawable(thumb_d);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // handle it
}
```

I have no idea what the second parameter to `Drawable.createFromStream` is, but passing `"src"` seems to work. If anyone knows, please shed some light, as the docs don't really say anything about it.

Comment: I'm sorry if this doesn't work, I have not tested it. I have edited my answer and added another method.

Comment: Other stackoverflow questions seem to indicate that "src" is useless.

Comment: Your snippet should not be used in U.I. thread, the network operation could block the application and triggers an ANR window. You have to use ASynctask or a background thread of your own to manage the downloads. There are some libraries like https://code.google.com/p/droid4me/wiki/BitmapDownloader that helps you manage image downloading the right way.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way so far is build a simple image retriver:

```
public Bitmap getRemoteImage(final URL aURL) {
    try {
        final URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        final BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        final Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
        bis.close();
        return bm;
    } catch (IOException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

Then, you just have to supply a URL to the method and it will returns a `Bitmap`. Then, you will just have to use the [`setImageBitmap`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29) method from `ImageView` to show the image.

Comment: would you know how to do this in an https connection?

Answer (score 6):

Be careful with both of the answers here - they both run the chance of an `OutOfMemoryException`. Test your application by attempting to download a large image, such as a desktop wallpaper. To be clear, the offending lines are :

`final Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);`

and

`Drawable thumb_d = Drawable.createFromStream(thumb_u.openStream(), "src");`

Felix's answer will catch it in the catch{} statement, and you could do something about it there.

Here is how to work around the `OutOfMemoryException` error:

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 8;
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    try {
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError ome) {
        // TODO - return default image or put this in a loop,
        // and continue increasing the inSampleSize until we don't
        // run out of memory
    }
```

And here are my comments on this in my code

```
/**
 * Showing a full-resolution preview is a fast-track to an
 * OutOfMemoryException. Therefore, we downsample the preview image. Android
 * docs recommend using a power of 2 to downsample
 * 
 * @see <a
 *      href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue/823966#823966">StackOverflow
 *      post discussing OutOfMemoryException</a>
 * @see <a
 *      href="http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize">Android
 *      docs explaining BitmapFactory.Options#inSampleSize</a>
 * 
 */
```

Links from above comments:
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue/823966#823966)
[Link 2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize)

Answer (score 6):

You can also try this lib:
https://github.com/codingfingers/fastimage

When we had few projects with the same pattern, and the lib came up ;) so why not to share with others...

Answer (score 4):

This is simple:

Add this dependency in you gradle script:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

*2.71828 is current version

Then do this for the image view:

```
Picasso.get().load(pictureURL).into(imageView);
```