# Android: Load Image from server

Tags: android

I was thinking, maybee the best way of loading pictures that I have on the server, using for my site would be to get the url for the picture..

How can I load picture from a url to ImageView?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading remote images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075637/loading-remote-images)

Answer (score 0):

I would say [setImageUri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageURI%28android.net.Uri%29) if I understood correctly what you're trying to do.