# The best way for displaying a remote image on Android?

Tags: android, image, imageview

I'm creating a simple application for Android which should display an image which is located on remote HTTP server. Which is the best way to do this: should it write the image to some temporary file, or just load it to RAM (in this case, how to load image to ImageView from byte array)?

Thank you all

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Load Image from server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111441/android-load-image-from-server)